# Loop Through Menu Items in MDI Parent Form in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need a way to loop through the menu items in a **MDI Parent Form**.

The reason why is because I am setting the **background** of the buttons when they are **activated** to show the user which ones they have **selected**.

The pictures below illustrates an example of `System Settings` being selected in the menu and the `child form` shown on the right.

Currently I achieve this using direct code:

```
systemManagementToolStripMenuItem.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

[image]

How can I loop through so that each time I click on a menu item it will change the background colour of the selected item.

Comment: Why not just hold the `ToolStripMenuItem` in a `List` and loop over the list?

Comment: Why is this MDI at all?  Why is there a Window menu when the selection is on the left?  Mysterious question...  Just ditch the menu completely and you don't have a problem you need to solve.

Comment: @HansPassant how else would you create a menu driven application? I'm super new to this whole environment with a MS Access background hence it seemed the best way with my limited knowledge

Comment: @cocojay I might wrongfully suspect you think MDI stands for Menu Driven; it stands for Multiple Document. The "main form" of you application can be either an `MDIParent` (has a `ClientArea` for forms to be "held" in) or not and just be a regular `Form`. // Just from the image I assume you might want to make the main form not an MDI container and just display various `UserControl` (Where each `UserControl` represents a "page" the menu item corresponds to) in a `Panel` based on which `ToolStripMenuItem` is selected?

Comment: @KDecker Yeah you're probably right. I'm not used to the concept of panels yet. This is just a first play around project for me teaching myself. But I like your idea on the Panel along the left side. So I would initiate the same panel for each form I open essentially. I'm probably not using the `MDI form` in the way that I was intended

Comment: @cocojay All good. But I think you mean a `Panel` on the right side? Basically in this image above create a `UserControl` and put the controls on the right on it (Filter code, name, desc, etc). When a user selects an option on the left side, for example "File", then display the `UserControl` with `DockStyle.Fill` inside of the `Panel` on the right. Each time a user selects and option display the `UserControl` corresponding to that option. To the user it will seem as if they are simply "switching pages". If you want to get more fancy, on your `UserControl` put a `TabControl` and nest pages.

Comment: @KDecker I didn't know what you meant by `user control` until I googled it. Just tried it out and your method is much slicker! Appreciate the help/ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just collect the `ToolStipMenuItems` into a `List` and loop over the list whenever the user performs the action to initiate the looping.

```
// First create the list of menu items
int selectedMenuItem = 0;
List<ToolStripMenuItem> menuItems = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>();
menuItems.Add(systemManagementToolStripMenuItem);

// When the user performs some action, such as pressing down arrow
selectedMenuItem = (selectedMenuItem + 1) % menuItems.Count;
UpdateSelectedItems();

// Have some method to update the buttons
public void UpdateSelectedItems()
{
    foreach(var item in menuItems)
        item.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    menuItems[selectedMenuItem].BackColor = Color.Gray;
}
```